# lxml xmlsyntaxerror: entity 'ouml' not defined

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing, lxml

I'm using lxml and python 3.5 for parsing an xml file.

My code so far is:

```
for event, element in etree.iterparse(source, tag="article"):
    for child in element:
        print (child.tag, child.text)
    element.clear()
```

when executing I get the following message after a while:

```
 lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'ouml' not defined, line 47, column 25
```

I'm having a DTD file with all the entities defined. How can I include the file or define the missing entities?

Comment: Hey not sure if this works, but try `etree.iterparse(source, tag="article",dtd_load=True,dtd_verification=True, resolve_entities=True)`. 
If you dont want the entities to be resolved you can try 
 `etree.iterparse(source, tag="article",resolve_entities=False)`

Comment: http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.iterparse-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:
I'm reading the DTD file for verification as CoderBC suggested:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import XMLSyntaxError
import sys
import os

source = sys.argv[1]
dtd = etree.DTD(file=sys.argv[2])#read DTD
count = 0
#iterate through nodes
for event, element in etree.iterparse(source, load_dtd=True):
   count += 1
   #print all children
   for child in element:
      print(child.tag, child.text)
element.clear()

print("Final Count :", count)
```